# MySQL - Most efficient way to select today's date with time as 00:00:00

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How do I select midnight of the current date?

`2013-03-27 00:00:00`

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   TableName
WHERE  dateColumn = CURDATE()
```

`CURDATE()` returns current date with time set as `00:00:00`.

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdb61/1)

Comment: Perfect, thanks J W.  I didn't know you can compare a date without a time to a full timestamp.

Answer (score 5):

```
mysql> select cast(current_date() as datetime);
+----------------------------------+
| cast(current_date() as datetime) |
+----------------------------------+
| 2013-03-27 00:00:00              |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```